# Sending smilies with a java messenger application?

Tags: java

How can I make a client able to send smilies to other clients?

Answer (score 4):

You can just search for the smiley character sequences on the receiving end and replace them with an image of the smiley before you display the message.

Answer (score 1):

Smileys are just pieces of text that gets rendered as an image by the client app e.g. ":)" or "[smile]". Basically what the client does, is search for these in the message and replaces them

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. You set the `HTMLEditorKit` as my `JEditorPane` editorKit. Then it can understand the html tags.